# Function that iterates over text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a total newbie to programming and have just begun my first project which is a simple login app.

So far my code looks like this:

```
def login_or_registration():
    user_choice = input("Login (L) or Registration (R)? ").lower()
    if user_choice == "l":
        print("You will be redirected to the login window.")
        login()
    elif user_choice == "r":
        print("You will be redirected to the registration window.")
        registration()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice.")


def registration():
    name = input("Name: ")
    surname = input("Surname: ")
    username = input("Username: ")
    pass1 = input("Password: ")
    pass2 = input("Repeat password: ")
    if pass1 != pass2:
        print("Passwords don't match!")
    email = input("E-mail: ")
    age = input("Age: ")
    while True:
        if not age.isdecimal():
            print("Please enter a number.")
        if not name.isalpha():
            print("Please use only letters for Name and Surname.")
        if not surname.isalpha():
            print("Please use only letters for Name and Surname.")
        break
    with open("userbase.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(username + "\n" + pass1 + "\n" + surname + "\n" + name + "\n" + email + "\n" + age + "\n" + "\n")
    f.close()
    user_choice = input("Would you like to log in now? (Y/N) ").lower()
    if user_choice == "y":
        login()
    else:
        "Quitting."


def login():
    logged_in = False
    username = input("USERNAME: ")
    password = input("PASSWORD: ")
    while logged_in == False:
        f = open("userbase.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            if line == username:
                logged_in = True
                print("Logged in!")
    print("User not found!")


login_or_registration()
```

I know its incomplete and messy but for now i want to work on a function for logging in. My idea was to create a function that would iterate over a text file and search for a match to the users input I know it's not perfect and could have many problems but for now I want to avoid modules. I wrote the function login() but it doesn't work and I don't have an idea how to make it run. My idea was to make an if statement that would be checked for every iteration of a for loop inside a while loop combined with a boolean that would be set to True after the statement is true.

Comment: How does looklike your file?

Comment: Can you post an example of what your .txt file would look like?

Comment: This is a sample user: mdunlop22
mdunlop
Dunlop
Michael
m@d.pl
32

Comment: But every sentence is in a different line and there is 1 line of space betwen users.

Comment: I figuted it out but thank you for trying to help

Comment: Code: with open("userbase.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    username = input("USERNAME: ")
    password = input("PASSWORD: ")
    if username and password in f:
        print("Logged in")
    else:
        print("!")